# How to force SQL developer to use imp/exp command while import/export

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

While importing or exporting oracle data dump using SQL Developer by default it is using `impdp` command for import and `expdp` command for export. But I want to import a dump which is exported using `exp` command, and for that i need to force SQL developer to use `imp` command instead of `impdp` command. And same for export.

Pleas help me if anyone knows how to in-force SQL developer to use `imp` for import instead of `impdp` and `exp` for export instead of `expdp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not going to happen

The Original `exp` utilitie became [DESUPPORTED as of 11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL3634).  Additionally, the [11.1](https://www.oracle.com/us/assets/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf) version of the database is no longer supported either.  SQL Developer isn't going to be "patched" to support unsupported Database version or unsupported database features.

For more information you can read the Compatibility Matrix for `exp`/`imp` which has Oracle [Doc ID 132904.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/132904_1.html) NOTE : You must have a valid support contract (and account) to access the Document. (copy+pasting information is against Oracle's term of use)

The `imp` utility seems to still be around for importing old exports.

## Workaround

Learn to use the command line.

Comment: Have you thought about using the exp/imp utilities directly in the Oracle Home? Ideally you want to use data pump, but if you really want to use the original export/import try doing it from the command prompt. You can also try to find a really old version of SQL Developer.

Comment: The `imp` tool is here to stay for the foreseeable future. And the `exp` tool is also still available (in 18.3 and 19.1) and works just fine.